# Swap even and odd bits of unsigned 8-bit integer

Tags: javascript, algorithm, functional-programming

The task:

> Given an unsigned 8-bit integer, swap its even and odd bits. The 1st
>   and 2nd bit should be swapped, the 3rd and 4th bit should be swapped,
>   and so on.
>
> For example, 10101010 should be 01010101. 11100010 should be 11010001.
>
> Bonus: Can you do this in one line?

My solutions:

```
// imperative:
function swap8BitInteger(bytes){
  let copiedBytes = '';
  for(let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i+=2) {
    copiedBytes+= `${bytes[i+1]}${bytes[i]}`;
  }
  return copiedBytes;
}

console.log(swap8BitInteger('11100010'));

// I don't know wether this qualifies as a one-liner
const swap8BitInteger2 = bytes => bytes.split('').reduce((acc, bit, idx) => {acc[idx % 2 === 0 ? idx + 1 : idx - 1] = bit;return acc;}, []).join('');

console.log(swap8BitInteger2('11100010'));

// Not sure wether this is still readable
const swap8BitInteger3 = bytes => bytes.split('').reduce((acc, _, idx) => idx % 2 ? acc : acc + bytes[idx + 1] + bytes[idx], '');

console.log(swap8BitInteger3('11100010'));
```

Would be interested to see an even shorter (and/or more readable) solution.

Comment: Are the input and output really supposed to be strings, and not 8-bit integers are the question said?

Comment: JS doesn't have (8 bit) Integer types. It only got numbers, i.e. leading zeros can't be displayed, therefore I took a string representation of an 8 bit Integer.

Comment: That is just a display issue, of course a JS Number can easily hold 8 bits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### OMDG arrays to manipulate bits

Bit manipulation is the most basic type of operation a computer can do. These days it can mess with 64 bit in one go. JS number (as signed int 32) is limited to 32 (to keep us in our place)

BTW JS has 8, 16, 32bit signed and unsigned arrays.

In JS you can write binary numbers with the `0b` prefix. Eg `0b111` is 7

To swap even odd, you shift all bits to the left `<< 1` (same as * 2) and mask out `& 0b10101010` the odd bits. The for the even you shift all bits to the right `>> 1` similar to `/2`, mask out the even bits `& 0b101010101` and add or or the result of the previous shift.

Example show two ways of doing the same thing.

```js
const swapEvenOdd = char => ((char << 1) & 0b10101010) | ((char >> 1) & 0b1010101);

const swapEvenOdd2 = char => ((char * 2) & 170) + ((char / 2) & 85);


console.log(swapEvenOdd(0b01100110).toString(2).padStart(8,"0"))
console.log(swapEvenOdd2(0b01100110).toString(2).padStart(8,"0"))
```

Comment: Im deeply ashamed for not having know this. -.-“

Comment: @thadeuszlay LOL not to worry, binary maths is a dying art in the world of programming. This not the first time I have seen strings and arrays used to manipulate bits.

Comment: Can you please explain to me each single step and why it is needed? E.g. why is `& 0b10101010` needed and afterwards `|` and then `((char >> 1) & 0b1010101)`?

Comment: @thadeuszlay The rundown on bitwise operators https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators The  `char & 0b1010` the right side is a mask. It removes any bits that are 0 in the mask from char.  eg 4bit `c = 1001`  `1001<<1=0010` then `0010&1010=0010`  then after or `|` shift right and mask `1001>>1=0100` (if JS had unsigned char (8bit) then would use `>>>` to remove extra top bit) then `0100&0101=0100`. Then the or  `0100 | 0010 = 0110` which is the answer

Comment: Ah, I now understand. Binary math isn't that difficult after all.